# Смена изображения в зависимости от показателя громкости микрофона

Tags: javascript, c++

У меня есть **100** кадров которые должны меняться подобно анимации отталкиваясь от значения громкости микрофона.
Пробовал с помощью **JS**, использовал `for` для всех фотографий и через `createElement` хотел что бы они заменяли друг-друга. Не удалось подключить анализатор (нашел частотный анализатор но не *dB*).
Подскажите как бы мне сделать подобное и не проще ли использовать **C++** для подобного (хочу использовать как плагин для **OBS**)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать по этой статье: [JavaScript практика: визуализация голоса с микрофона. Web Audio API](http://prog-time.ru/web-audio-api-praktika-vizualizatsiya-golosa-s-mikrofona) но у меня что-то не получилось, выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Сделайте это на хостинге **https://**, тогда должно получиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишете, что кадры должны менять друг друга в зависимости от значений амплитуды сигнала с микрофона и при этом хотите использовать анализатор. Но в этом случае больше подойдёт **createMediaStreamSource()**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Визуализатор</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Визуализатор</h1>
<button onclick="start(); this.disabled = true"> Старт </button><br /><br />
<img id=myimg />
<br /><br />
<div id=mydiv></div>
<script>
var sensitivity = 10 // во сколько раз нужно поднять чувствительность
function start(){
    var db = 4096; // длина буфера чтения со входа звуковой карты
    audioCtx = new AudioContext;
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream){
        var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.node = source.context.createScriptProcessor.call(source.context, db, 1);
    source.node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
        var index = Math.min(Math.floor(Math.abs(100 * e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)[0] * sensitivity)), 99);
        mydiv.innerText = index;
        myimg.src = "kadr" + index + ".png"
    }
    source.connect(source.node);
    source.node.connect(source.context.destination);
    }, function(){alert("Что-то пошло не так")});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Этот пример работает на локалке, локальном сервере и на хостинге https. Но если хотите использовать анализатор, то тогда изображениям лучше выстроиться в ряд, и чтобы высота каждого кадра менялась синхронно значению соответствующей частоты:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Анализатор</title>
<style>
img{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 128px;
    width: 6px;
    top: 120px;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Анализатор</h1>
<button onclick="start(); this.disabled = true"> Старт </button>
<script>
var num = 128, // количество частотных полос
steep = 8; // шаг между полосами в пикселях
for(i = 0; i < 128; i ++){
    var kadr = document.createElement("img");
    kadr.id = "k" + i;
    kadr.src = "kadr" + i + ".png";
    kadr.style.left = i * steep + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(kadr);
}
function start(){
    audioCtx = new AudioContext;
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream){
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = num * 2;
    source.connect(analyser);
 // analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination); // Только если нужно через динамики слушать звук с микрофона
    var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    setInterval(function(){
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData); // Записываем в массив данные уровней частот
        for(i = 0; i < num; i ++) document.getElementById("k" + i).style.height = frequencyData[i] + "px";
    }, 20);
}, function(){alert("Что-то пошло не так")});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Имена графических файлов с кадрами в обоих примерах должны быть формата **"kadr35.png"**, где скажем 35 - это порядковый номер кадра, начиная с ноля.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, я попробовал подключить и у меня определяет только первые два кадра на любой другой показатель выдаёт ошибку kadr%20(-11).png:1 GET file:///Z:/Blender%20work/Done/Render/Hat%20light/kadr%20(-11).png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Получается мне надо их пронумеровать как -1, -2, -3 и тд. ?

Comment: И при таком варианте придётся делать чувствительность выше тк. с нынешним вариантом выше 10-13 подняться не получится, а расчёт на 100 и больше кадров, может  поможет чтоб результат отображался в десятичных?

Comment: **%20** означает, что в имени графического файла есть пробел, нужно либо удалить пробелы из имён файлов, либо одну строку переписать так: **kadr.src = "kadr " + i + ".png";** т к должно быть соответствие. Я исправил в ответе в первом примере ошибку, из-за которой появлялись отрицательные числа. Сейчас они могут быть только в пределах от 0 до 99 и отображаются на странице в десятичном виде. Так же создал переменную **sensitivity** с помощью которой можно увеличить чувствительность микрофона.

Comment: Работает здорово, только почему-то теперь при неактивности микрофона он включает 50-ый кадр вместо 0-го. И пока не забыл, смогу я сменить функцию на 'window.onload'? Мне необходим запуск сразу после открытия.

Comment: К сожалению,не сможете. Ни один из актуальных браузеров сейчас не поддерживает старт мультимедиа после загрузки страницы.

Comment: А тишина соответствовала 50-у кадру из-за того, что аудиосигнал содержит положительную и отрицательную область значений, но я переделал так, что теперь тишина соответствует нолю, а отрицательные волны преобразовываются в положительные и так же, как и положительные стремятся к 99. Мне кажется, что так будет лучше. В ответе исправил.

Comment: Спасибо всё работает, попробую поискать варианты тогда как запустить без кнопки, может через таймер.

Comment: Таймер не поможет, если после загрузки и до того, как он сработает, нигде не кликните, или не нажмёте на клавишу, или не прокрутите страницу.